# Do I need to thin sprouts from an avocado pit?

Tags: avocado

I'm growing avocado from a pit. I've always had only one sprout growing out of a pit but this one has 3 sprouts. I'm wondering if I can leave it as it is or have to thin it. [image: an avocado pit with multiple sprouts]

Comment: n.b. avocados are highly variable, commercial avocados are all clones. the fruit will not taste like the parent fruit, also the time it takes for the new tree to produce fruit can vary by up to a decade!

Comment: The newer avocados tend to produce trees with fruit that is true.

Comment: @grahamchiu - Thats an interesting statement - can you expand on it?

Comment: No luck finding the link where I read this yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leave it the way it is.  Most likely 2 of the shoots will die off as Avocados have strong apical dominance.  If this doesnt happen, having multiple shoots won't hurt the tree.  (Multiple shoots apparently also indicates is a very good plant)